# Searching for records with an accent without an accent in my criteria

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, collation

I have a record in the database which is:

`Alverá`

However if I run:

`SELECT * FROM PHONEBOOK WHERE NAME = 'Alvera'`

Nothing gets returned.

How do I set the database collation so that i don't need to keep modifying my queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just looking to alter your column's collation property, you could just do something like this:

```
/* Change the database collation */
ALTER TABLE PHONEBOOK
ALTER COLUMN NAME VARCHAR(50)
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CI_AI NULL --change this to match your collation needs
```

You will want to select a collation name that has **AI** in it. `AI` specifies accent-insensitive.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd4d32/1/0)